# Truffle and Ganache-cli test case fails

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, ganache

So I have this setup : `truffle` and `ganache-cli`

I'm sending some ether to my contract, here is the related part of my contract:

```
    mapping(address => uint256) public balanceOf;

    function () payable public {
              uint amount = msg.value;
              balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;
        }
```

In truffle this is how I send the ether.

```
it("Test if can be payed", function(){
    return web3.eth.sendTransaction({
           from:fromAddr, 
           to:MyContract.address,  
           value:amountToSend
    }).then(function(res){  
           expect(res).to.not.be.an("error"); // test passed
    });
 });

it("Test if contract received ether", function(){
        return web3.eth.getBalance(MyContract.address, 
               function(err, res){
                        expect(parseInt(res)).to.be.at.least(1000000000000000000); // test passed
                });
});

it("Catch if balanceOf "+fromAddr, function(){
        return sale.balanceOf.call(fromAddr).then(function(res){
                        expect(parseInt(res)).to.be.at.least(1); // fails the test
               });
});
```

Am I doing it right? What could be the reason for failed test?
truffle test output :

```
AssertionError: expected 0 to be at least 1
      + expected - actual

      -0
      +1
```

I can provide more info if needed.

Comment: Checking if `parseInt(res)` returns 1000000000000000000 may possibly fail, since Javascript's max safe integer (`Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`) is much smaller (`2 ^ 53 - 1` to be accurate).

Comment: In general, don't use `parseInt` on `res`. If I'm not mistaken, then `res` is a `BigNumber` (or a `BN` in later versions of web3.js). This class has all the functionality that you need, for example, `greaterThan`, `equals`, etc. If I'm wrong and `res` is a string, then convert it to a `BigNumber`.

Comment: In general, I'd replace `expect(parseInt(res)).to.be.at.least(1000000000000000000)` with `assert(res.greaterThanOrEqualTo("1000000000000000000"))`, and `expect(parseInt(res)).to.be.at.least(1)` with `assert(res.greaterThanOrEqualTo("1"))`.

Comment: I've changed as per your suggestion, but the same case fail

Comment: I believe that you should change `balanceOf.call(fromAddr)` to `balanceOf(fromAddr).call()`.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `call` and `send` take an object which specifies `from`, `gas`, etc.

Comment: I can use `call(Address)` or `balanceOf(Address)` both produce same error.
I you look at my code I send ether with web3js and when I read values from contract I use truffle, is this correct way to do it? Can I send ether using truffle only ?

Comment: Yes, though your terminology is wrong; Truffle is a testing framework (based on Mocha framework for `it`, `before`, `after`, etc). Web3 is a protocol for communicating with an Ethereum node (Ganache in your case). With `sale.balanceOf.call`, you are not "doing it with Truffle". The call is eventually translated into a web3 message to Ganache. If you want to send ether in a "normal" function call (i.e., without `web3.eth.sendTransaction`), then just give a name to your fallback function (currently declared as `function () payable public`), and call it the same way you call function `balanceOf`.

Comment: And of course, you can omit the `to:MyContract.address` if you choose to do it this way. I think it might cost slightly more than the 21000 gas units that `web3.eth.sendTransaction` costs (perhaps 21000 + 2300 gas units, but I'm honestly not certain about this).

Answer (score 1):

As I've mentioned in the comments, there are a number of problems in your code:

- Calling `parseInt(res)` may lead to an incorrect result, since `res` is a `BigNumber` possibly larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`
- Using `1000000000000000000` may lead to an incorrect result, since it is larger than `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

I'm not sure what exactly the cause of your failure, since I always use `async`/`await` instead of `then` where possible.

But in any case, this seems to be working fine:

```
contract("Sale", function(accounts) {
    let sale;
    let fromAddr = accounts[0];
    let amountToSend = "1000000000000000000";

    before(async function() {
        sale = await artifacts.require("Sale").new();
    });

    it("Test if can be payed", async function() {
        let res = await web3.eth.sendTransaction({
            from: fromAddr, 
            to: sale.address,  
            value: amountToSend
        });
        // if we reach here then the transaction has completed successfully
    });

    it("Test if contract received ether", async function() {
        let res = await web3.eth.getBalance(sale.address);
        assert(res.greaterThanOrEqualTo(amountToSend));
    });

    it("Catch if balanceOf "+fromAddr, async function() {
        let res = await sale.balanceOf.call(fromAddr);
        assert(res.greaterThanOrEqualTo(1));
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you please tell me if I need to add a module for `greaterThanOrEqualTo` ? `TypeError: res.greaterThanOrEqualTo is not a function` this what I get when I use your code.

Comment: Maybe the problem is with my setup, but using async/await did not solve my issue

Comment: What version of `BigNumber` are you using? Or more precisely, what version of `web3` are you using (since `web3` imports `BigNumber` into your system)? Or more precisely, what version of `truffle` are you using (since `truffle` imports `web3` into your system)? You possibly need to change `greaterThanOrEqualTo` to `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo`.